# Biggest rebrands of 2021or Biggest rebrands in 2021. Which is correct?

Tags: prepositions

'Biggest rebrands of 2021' or 'Biggest rebrands in 2021'. Which is correct?

Comment: Hello shanila and welcome to ELL! We expect people creating questions to show that they have done some thinking and hopefully some research on their own and describe what they found and what aspects of it they are still unsure about. [How do I write a good question?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). This question will likely get [closed](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both make sense, but 'Biggest rebrands of 2021' sounds more natural.